# How to iterate loop inside a string searching for any word aftera fixed keyword?

Tags: php, string, for-loop

Suppose I have a sting as "PHP Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth", now i have a count as 3,now how should I iterate loop in the string aiming on string after "PHP " to display the all the names?

Alright This is the string "`BEGIN IF (NEW.name != OLD.name) THEN INSERT INTO jos_menuaudit set menuid=OLD.id, oldvalue = OLD.name, newvalue = NEW.name, field = "name"; END IF; IF (NEW.alias != OLD.alias) THEN INSERT INTO jos_menuaudit set menuid=OLD.id, oldvalue = OLD.alias, newvalue = NEW.alias, field = "alias"; END IF; END`"  in which i am searching the particular word after " `IF (NEW.`", and after that particualar others strings should not b displayed, hence whenever in a loop it finds " `IF (NEW.`" I musr get a word just next to it. and in this way an array should b ready for to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`explode`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`substr`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$str =  "PHP Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth";    
$ary = explode(',', $str);
foreach($ary as $str){
   echo substr($str, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can (more or less) "combine" the explode() and substr() thingy into one call of [preg_match_all()](http://docs.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
$pattern = '/(?<=PHP )[^,]+/';
$input = "PHP Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth";
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $captures);
foreach( $captures[0] as $e ) {
  echo $e, "\n";
}
```

prints

```
Paddy
Pranav
Parth
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str =  "PHP Paddy Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth";
$s = array_filter(preg_split("/,|PHP/",$str));
print_r($s);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
$str = "PHP Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth";
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $p) {
    echo substr($p,4)."\n";
}
```

- First we split the string on comma to
  get an array with `3` elements
- Next we iterate through the array and
  print each element skipping the first
  `4` char.

Answer (score 0):

Also can use `strstr`

```
$str = "PHP Paddy,PHP Pranav,PHP Parth";
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $st) {
echo strstr($st,' ')."\n";
}
```