# How to search for a string in a text?

Tags: php

What i want to do is search for a text/words within a long text like:

```
$txt = 'text das text dss text good text text bad text';
```

and i want to search for `good text` in this `$txt` without using PHP functions like `stripos()` or others, i want to use just `for` in PHP and make minimum loops as possible.

How can i go through all the `$txt` searching for `good text` and getting what is after it?

Comment: Not even regex functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528736/how-to-iterate-loop-inside-a-string-searching-for-any-word-aftera-fixed-keyword

Comment: I REALLY DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY DOWNGRADE !!! It's a real question!!!

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky not even regex :) any ideas? you can use `isset()`

Comment: @Jimmy, `isset()` is not a function , its a `language construct`

Comment: Why don't you use php functions ???? Any thing wrong with them

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yep, i want to use only `isset()`

Comment: Asking PHP to run a marathon without legs :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky well this is the challenge! :) and i really don't get the downgrade, it's a challenge' and it's true not a fake question!

Comment: I didn't down vote your post, but can't defend others. Everyone has their own reasoning. One reason for these down votes will surely be the fact that you did not provide any code you tried yourself. Just asked a question without showing your own research effort

Comment: Two nested for-loops issn't really a challenge...

Comment: @Yoshi in some cases it is ;)

Comment: Ok, check it out - I used only `while` and `isset` and of course `if`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function findRemaining($needle, $haystack) {
  $result = '';

  for ($i = 0, $found = false; isset($haystack[$i]); $i += 1) {
    if (!$found) {
      for ($j = 0; isset($haystack[$i + $j], $needle[$j]); $j += 1) {
        if ($haystack[$i + $j] !== $needle[$j]) {
          continue 2;
        }
      }

      $found = true;
    }

    $result .= $haystack[$i];
  }

  return $result;
}

$haystack = 'text das text dss text good text text bad text';
$needle = 'good text';

// string(23) "good text text bad text"
var_dump(
  findRemaining($needle, $haystack)
);
```

Comment: +1 ... Well Yoshi :) you answer is amazing! Thanks! your approach is really interesting

Comment: after checking, the var_dump for your result withing a custom function is returning only the first letter => 'g' ...

Comment: I changed the answer to give an example of how to collect the result and return it from a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $txt = 'text das text dss text good text text bad text';
  $search = 'good text';

  $pos = -1;

  $i = 0;

  while (isset($txt{$i})) {
    $j = 0;

    $wrong = false;

    while (isset($search{$j})) {
      if ($search{$j} != $txt{$i + $j}) {
        $wrong = true;

        break;
      }

      $j++;
    }

    if (!$wrong) {
      $pos = $i;

      break;
    }

    $i++;
  }

  echo 'Position: '.$pos; // in your case it will return position: 23
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but i don't want to use any php functions for implementing this, can you do it please without the strlen, substr ? Thanks again!

Comment: How you would do `for` without knowing length of `$txt` and `$search`??? Can I use `while`?

Comment: +1 ... It's working, the position is correct, one question though, how can i make the display to be from that position to the end of the text: `good text text bad text`? Thanks very much!

Comment: LOL, at least +1, but not even that.. that +1 was from someone else :D

Comment: I up voted you Legionar. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and let me know...

```
$txt = "text das text dss text good text text bad text";
function search_string($word, $text){
 $parts = explode(" ", $text);
 $result = array();
 $word = strtolower($word);

 foreach($parts as $v){

  if(strpos(strtolower($v), $word) !== false){
   $result[] = $v;
  }
 }
 if(!empty($result)){
    return implode(", ", $result);
 }else{
    return "Not Found";
 }
}
echo search_string("text", $txt);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but again, i needed an implementation without PHP functions... like Yoshi's answer. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `preg_match` here. do you want example related to this ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but only isset() is ok to use